# Check block binaries git hook

Tags: git, perl, hook

Here is a pre-recieve git hook, that should block files, if the are binary

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
###########################################
use strict; 
use warnings;

our $host = `uname -n`;chomp $host;
our $repo = `pwd`;chomp;

if (  $repo =~ /^(.+)\.git/ ){
   $repo = $1;
}
$repo =~ /([^\/]+)$/;
$repo = $1;
chomp $repo;


print "========================================================\n";
print "GIT hook.....: pre-commit\n";
print "GIT server...: $host \n";
print "GIT Repo.....: $repo \n";
print "========================================================\n";

my @new_file_list =  `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A`;
foreach $file (@new_file_list)
{
  chomp($file);

  # Check if file is binary
  if (-B $file)
  {
    print STDERR "WARNING: $file is binary.\n";
    print STDERR "Please check with repo owner before committing binary files.\n";
    print STDERR "To bypass this warning re-run your commit with the '--no-verify' option\n";
    exit 1;
  }
}
```

Could you tell me, how can I check, if it works properly?

I was trying to create a binary file like this

```
echo -n -e \\x48\\x00\\x49\\x00 > myfile
```

or this

```
echo "0000 4865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 6421 0000" > text_dump
xxd -r -p text_dump > binary_dump
```

But when I push them, this hook doesn't block these files.

Comment: not really. How can I create a binary file to make this hook triggered?

Comment: You can generate a file which satisfies the criteria: "The first block or so of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange control codes or characters with the high bit set. If too many strange characters (>30%) are found, it’s a -B file;"

Answer (score 1):

You filled your file with the string, "Hello world!" which not qualifies as binary according to `perldoc -f -B`

> The first block or so of the file is examined for odd characters such
>   as strange control codes or characters with the high bit set. If too
>   many strange characters (>30%) are found, it’s a -B file;

You can try generating a byte sequence that satisfies this condition or copy a part of one of your binary with `head -c` into a file.

Comment: I was trying to put big .exe files and push them, but the hook doesn't throw a error. Why can it be? Does it mean, that the hook doesn't work

Comment: Test your binary with `perl -e "print (-B 'yourbinary')?'binary':'text';"` (it may contain errors, i don't have acces to perl now)

Comment: Do you see your header lines? (GIT hook, etc.) Maybe the hook does not start.

Comment: no, the hook starts

Comment: somehow when I use **perl -e "print (-B 'mybinaryfile')?'binary':'text';"**, it prints nothing.

Comment: You need additional parentheses `perl -e "print ((-B '/bin/ls')?'binary':'text');"`

Comment: tried it, the result is the same **perl -e "print ((-B '/home/ilyab/testingfoulder/yulia_cm_test/_kssh.exe')?'binary':'text');"**

Comment: On my debian system (perl v5.20.2) it gives me "binary" with /bin/ls.

Comment: and mine is Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: wow, it works, I was my fault, didn't pay attention to it.